# CSS: Both background color and image, Why?

Tags: css

I came across something like this below. Why not just use image? When do we need to use both?

```
background: #6DB3F2 url('images/checked.png')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any of the other answers cover all the (practical) reasons, so here goes:

1. If the background image has transparent parts, then the background color would show.
2. If the background image is smaller than the document (e.g. only used as a header image), then the background color would span the rest of the document.
3. If the background image fails to load (e.g. server error on host, 404, or government blacklist *cough*China*cough*)
4. Sort of a derivative to #3, the background color will be shown while the background image loads. If you set the background color to be the same as (or similar to) that of the image, then there won't be a sudden change in colour when the image loads.

Answer (score 1):

If the image has transparency, you may want to show color behind it. The image may only cover part of the background of the container, while you may want the rest of the container to have a background color. Those would be the primary reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use only image.

try

```
background:url('images/checked.png');
```

but for while the image is still loading/rendering, it is best to show background color first.

so use

```
background: #6DB3F2 url('images/checked.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we need to color the background if the image is small and not repeated or has transparent area

Answer (score 0):

1. Background image doesn't have to be the same size of the element, so the  color will fill other part of the element.
2. Background image can be transparent, you can fill transparent sections with the color.